# dealing with files and structures in c

Tags: c, file, visual-c++, struct

while i'm working on my manii project phonebook , i faced some problems in delete function when there are multi result for the same first name (i use first name to search about the contact that i want to delete)
in this case i made extra variable in my structure called "ID" and this ID Auto fill in my program (so each user has a unique id) , so i can later find exactly the result that the user want to delete it ,and it works fine , but when i delete a contact from the file it left me with a gap and this effect on the next contact 
For Example :

> i have 3 contacts each one has an iD 1 , 2 and 3 , when i delete No.2 , it become 1 and 3 , when i add a new user my Auto fill loop will count the number of the contacts (2) and give the new one ID of  3 , that left me with 3 contacts with ID of 1 , 3 , and 3 and this's wrong

so i came with an idea to Reset all the IDs after each Delete operation , it seems good for me and this few line should do it , i don't know why this part doesn't work , even i tried to put this loop in add() function so it should be good at this position too , but it doesn't work too

```
// reset all ids
                rewind(ft);
                int id=1;
                while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft)==1)
                {
                    p.id = id;
                    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft);
                    id++;
                }
```

> This is my Full code with 0 Errors and 0 warning , and it work fine except the part of reset ids

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct address  // nested
{

    char city[30],
         street[30];
    int  flat;

};

struct phonebook  // main
{
    int id;
    char firstName[20],
         lastName[20];
    struct address add;
    long int  phNumber;
    char email[50];

};


// functions ...
void launcher();
void menu();
void add();
void load();
void query();
void Delete();
void modify();
void back();
void scan(char *name);

int main()
{
    system("color 1e");
    printf("Let's start!\n");
    launcher();
    return 0;
}

void launcher()
{
    menu();
}

void back()
{
    menu();
}

void menu()
{

    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t      *********** PhoneBook! *************");

    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  <| Menu |>\t\t\n\n");
    printf("\t\t1.Add   \t2.Load   \t3.Query  \n\t\t4.Modify \t5.Delete\t6.Exit\n");

    switch(getch())
    {
    case '1' :
        add();
        break;

    case '2' :
        load();
        break;

    case '3' :
        query();
        break;

    case '4' :
        modify();
        break;

    case '5' :
        Delete();
        break;

    case '6' :
        printf("the program exit successfully");
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        system("cls");

        int i;
        for(i=15 ; i>-1 ; i--)
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("\nInvalid key Entered , please enter any key from 1 to 6 only!\n");
            printf("you will back to the main menu automatically in %d seconds",i);
            Sleep(1000);
        }

        menu();


    }

}

void add()
{
    system("cls");
    struct phonebook p; // local define
    FILE *f;
    f= fopen("data","ab+");
    int id=1;

    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
    {
        id++;
    }


    printf("\nFirst Name : ");
    scan(p.firstName);
    printf("\nLast Name : ");
    scan(p.lastName);

    printf("\nEnter the address .. ");
    printf("\n\tCity : ");
    scan(p.add.city);
    printf("\n\tStreet : ");
    scan(p.add.street);
    printf("\n\tFlat : ");
    scanf(" %d",&p.add.flat);

    printf("\nPhone number : ");
    scanf(" %ld",&p.phNumber);
    printf("\nEmail : ");
    scan(p.email);
    p.id=id; // Auto fill
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,f); // saving the data into a file
    fclose(f);

    puts("\n\n\t\tdata is saved successfully!");
    puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
    getch();
    back();
}

void load()
{
    struct phonebook p;
    system("cls");
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("data","rb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        puts("\n An error occur while opening the file >");

        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
    {

        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  <| loading List |>\t\t\n\n");
        printf("First name : %s\nLast name : %s\nAddress Info ...\nCity : %s\nStreet : %s\nFlat : %d\nPhone Number : %ld\nEmail : %s\nid : %d\n",p.firstName,p.lastName,p.add.city,p.add.street,p.add.flat,p.phNumber,p.email,p.id);

        puts("\t\t * Enter any key to show more *");
        getch();
        system("cls");
    }

    fclose(f);
    puts("\t\tno more data to show !");
    puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
    getch();
    back();




}

void query()
{

    system("cls");
    struct phonebook p;
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("data","rb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        puts("\n An error occur while opening the file >");

        exit(1);
    }

    char name[50];
    int flag=0;
    printf("please enter a name : ");
    scan(name);
    system("cls");
    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
    {

        if(strcmp(name,p.firstName)==0)
        {
            flag++;
            printf("\n[%d] result found\n",flag); // ==> static text
            printf("First name : %s\nLast name : %s\nAddress Info ...\nCity : %s\nStreet : %s\nFlat : %d\nPhone Number : %ld\nEmail : %s\n",p.firstName,p.lastName,p.add.city,p.add.street,p.add.flat,p.phNumber,p.email);

            puts("");
        }
    }

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        puts("file not found");
    }

    fclose(f);
    puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
    getch();
    back();
}

void modify()
{

    system("cls");
    struct phonebook p,s;
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("data","rb+");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        puts("\n An error occur while opening the file >");

        exit(1);
    }

    char name[50];
    int flag=0;
    printf("please enter a name : ");
    scan(name);
    system("cls");
    int results[50];
    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
    {

        if(strcmp(name,p.firstName)==0)
        {
            results[flag] = p.id;
            flag++;
            printf("\n\n >> full information about the result No. [%d] :- \n",p.id);
            printf("First name : %s\nLast name : %s\nAddress Info ...\nCity : %s\nStreet : %s\nFlat : %d\nPhone Number : %ld\nEmail : %s\n",p.firstName,p.lastName,p.add.city,p.add.street,p.add.flat,p.phNumber,p.email);

        }
    }

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        puts("file not found");
    }
    else
    {
        int choice,i,found=0;
        int lastResultID = p.id;
        puts("Please enter the Number of the result to confirm your order");
        scanf(" %d",&choice);
        // confirmation
        for(i=0 ; i<flag ;i++){
            if(results[i] == choice){
                found =1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == 0){
            puts("\n Ops! Result not found.\nmaybe you entered a wrong No. OR an Error occurs Try again.");
            Sleep(5000);
            back();
        }else{

            //printf("\n%d\n",lastResultID);
            puts("\n >> Are you want to modify this result ? type (Y) for Yes or (N) for No !");
            char c = getch();
            if( c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\nFirst Name : ");
                scan(s.firstName);
                printf("\nLast Name : ");
                scan(s.lastName);

                printf("\nEnter the address .. ");
                printf("\n\tCity : ");
                scan(s.add.city);
                printf("\n\tStreet : ");
                scan(s.add.street);
                printf("\n\tFlat : ");
                scanf(" %d",&s.add.flat);

                printf("\nPhone number : ");
                scanf(" %ld",&s.phNumber);
                printf("\nEmail : ");
                scan(s.email);
                fseek(f,-sizeof(p)*(lastResultID-choice+1),SEEK_CUR);
                s.id=choice;
                fwrite(&s,sizeof(p),1,f); // saving

                puts("\n\t\tyour data is modified!");
                fclose(f);
                puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
                getch();
                back();


            }
            else
            {

                system("cls");
                puts("nothing change ! , press any key to back to the main menu !");
                getch();
                back();

            }

        }



    }

}

void Delete()
{
    int found =0;
    system("cls");
    struct phonebook p,s;
    FILE* f;
    FILE* ft;
    f = fopen("data","rb");
    ft = fopen("temp","ab+");
    if(f == NULL || ft == NULL)
    {
        puts("\n An error occur while opening the file >");
        perror("fopen() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    char name[50];
    int flag=0,i;
    int results[50];
    printf("please enter a name : ");
    scan(name);
    system("cls");
    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
    {

        if(strcmp(name,p.firstName)==0)
        {
            results[flag] = p.id;
            flag++;
            printf("\n\n >> full information about the result No. [%d] :- \n",p.id);
            printf("First name : %s\nLast name : %s\nAddress Info ...\nCity : %s\nStreet : %s\nFlat : %d\nPhone Number : %ld\nEmail : %s\n",p.firstName,p.lastName,p.add.city,p.add.street,p.add.flat,p.phNumber,p.email);

        }
    }



    if(flag == 0)
    {
        puts("file not found");
    }
    else{
        puts(" ");
        int choice,check=0;
        puts("please enter the number of the result which you want to delete");
        scanf("  %d",&choice);

        // confirmation
        for(i=0 ; i<flag ;i++){
            if(results[i] == choice){
                check =1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(check == 0){
            puts("\n Oops! Result not found.\nmaybe you entered a wrong No. OR an Error occurred Try again later.");
            Sleep(3500);
            back();
        }else{

            puts("\n >> Do you want to delete this result ? type (Y) for Yes or (N) for No !");
            char c = getch();
            rewind(f); // reset the pointer
            if( c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            {
                system("cls");
                while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)

                {
                    if(choice != p.id)
                        fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft);
                    if(choice == p.id)
                        found++;
                }

                //perror("fread() failed");



                if(found == 0)
                {
                    puts("An error occurred , please try again");
                    remove("temp");
                    Sleep(3500);
                    back();

                    fclose(f); // ==?
                    fclose(ft); // ==?
                }
                else
                {
                    // reset all ids
                    rewind(ft);
                    int id=1;
                    while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft)==1)
                    {
                        p.id = id;
                        fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft);
                        id++;
                    }

                    fclose(f); // ==?
                    fclose(ft); // ==?

                    remove("data");
                    int c = rename("temp","data");
                    puts("file is deleted successfully");

                    if(c != 0)
                        perror("rename() failed"); // handling for rename error



                }

                puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
                getch();
                back();




            }
            else
            {

                system("cls");
                puts("nothing changed ! , press any key to back to the main menu !");
                getch();
                back();

            }


        }


        }


    /*else
    {

        puts("\n >> Are you want to delete this result ? type (Y) for Yes or (N) for No !");
        char c = getch();
        if( c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
        {

            rewind(f);
            while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
            {
                if(strcmp(name,p.firstName)!=0)
                    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,ft);
            }

            fclose(f);
            fclose(ft);

            remove("data");
            int c = rename("temp","data");
            puts("file is deleted successfully");

            if(c != 0)
                perror("rename() failed");

            // reset all ids
            int id=1;
            while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
            {
                p.id = id;
                fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,f);
                id++;
            }
            puts("\t\tEnter any key to back to the main menu");
            getch();
            back();

        }
        else
        {

            system("cls");
            puts("nothing change ! , press any key to back to the main menu !");
            getch();
            back();
        }
    }*/


}

void scan(char *name)
{

    int i=0,j;
    char c,ch;
    do
    {
        c=getch();
        if(c!=8&&c!=13)
        {
            *(name+i)=c;
            putch(c);
            i++;
        }
        if(c==8)
        {
            if(i>0)
            {
                i--;
            }
            // printf("h");
            system("cls");
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                ch=*(name+j);
                putch(ch);

            }

        }
    }
    while(c!=13);
    *(name+i)='\0';
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" means exactly what? What happens? What does not happen, what you expect to happen? Did you run this inside a debugger, tracing the code line be line, checking the relevant variables, to learn what is really going on

Comment: p.id = id; ==> s.id = id;?

Comment: @alk "it doesn't work" means i doesn't reset the ids for me like this lines wasn't exist , and yes i tried to debug and trace the code , and what i find is the output of this loop is wright and the loop works fine , but the new value of the the id didn't updated in the file , and i don't understand why , also i used perror() like u told be before to find what is the problem with fwrite() inside the loop but no error.

Comment: @koper89 forget about s , i just tried to use another variable of the structure in this loop , but it doesn't work too , and i forget to edit the rest of the code , i edit it now

Comment: It wouldn't be much easier for you if you would just delete this .id in structure? and id would be based on order? It would solve all your problems. Currently anyway you use this id like it's in order so why you need this redundancy?

Comment: @koper89 the program deleted all the contact with id , the problem about the mechanism of putting  id for a new user , when i need to put a new id for a new  user , i made a loop to count the number of all users , then give it the next id number for the next user (new) , when i have this gap , it would be an error for me because last 2 user in my list would have the same id , try to run my code and add for example 3 contacts  and delete 1 of them , then add a new one , and press 2  to see the list of , and u will find what i mean

Answer (score 1):

What about using the highest id+1 instead of counting them?

```
int id = 1;
while(fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,f)==1)
{
    if (p.id >= id) id = p.id+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interleave `fread` and `fwrite` without an intervening `fseek`:

> **7.21.5.3/7** When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

Comment: i used rewind()